# Validating arguments before executing a function

Tags: r, function, validation, arguments

I want to validate that each of the two arguments I'm passing to a function are valid.

To do this, I'm checking to see if the 'State' value I assign to my 'state' variable is in a list of states, 'statelist'. Then I check to see if the 'Measure' value I assign to my 'measure' variable is in my list of measures, 'measurelist'. If the first check fails, an "invalid state" error message should be generated. If the second check fails, an "invalid measure" error message should be produced. If both checks pass, I want the function lowest <- function(state, measure) to run.

This is my dataframe, 'data':

```
school<-c("NYU", "BYU", "USC", "FIT", "Oswego","UCLA","USF","Columbia")
state<-c("NY","UT","CA","NY","NY","CA", "CA","NY")
measure<-c("MSAT","MSAT","GPA","MSAT","MSAT","GPA","GPA","GPA")
score<-c(590, 490, 2.9, 759, 550, 1.2, 3.1, 3.2)
data<-data.frame(school,state, measure,score)
```

This function checks that I have a valid state abbreviation:

```
teststate<-function(state){
  statelist<-(c(state.abb,"DC","GU","MP","PR","VI"))
  if(state %in% statelist){
    testmeasure(measure)
  } else{
    stop("invalid state")
  }
 }
```

This function checks that the measure I'm specifying is in my list of measures:

```
testmeasure<-function(measure){ 
    measurelist<-c("MSAT","GPA","VSAT")
    if(measure %in% measurelist){
      lowest(state, measure)
    } else{
      stop("invalid measure")
    }
  }
```

This is the main function that should run after the validity checks are successful:

```
lowest <- function(state, measure){
    answer<-subset(data,subset=(state==State & measure==Measure))
    order.answer<-order(answer$score,answer$school)
    answer1<-as.matrix(answer[order.answer,])
    answer1[1,1]
  }
```

For this example:

```
lowest("NY","MSAT")
```

the correct answer should be [1] "Owsego", but when I run the code in its entirety, it never completes, and the console simply shows:

```
+ lowest("NY","MSAT")
+
```

When I tested each of these modules independently, outside of a function, they worked.

Comment: Where's those plus signs come from? They're usually R's continuation prompts, meaning you havent closed a bracket or a " and R wants a bit more.

Comment: Just out of curisoity, ever thought of using `stopifnot()`?

Comment: I get a different error, because you've got "State" in your "lowest" function but the data frame you construct has "state" in lower case and R is case sensitive. If you fix that (and fix "Measure" for "measure") then I get "Oswego".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
lowestV2 <- function(State,Measure){
  ##
  if(State %in% c(state.abb,"DC","GU","MP","PR","VI")){
    if(Measure %in% c("MSAT","GPA","VSAT")){
      answer<-subset(data,subset=(state==State & measure==Measure))
      order.answer<-order(answer$score,answer$school)
      answer1<-as.matrix(answer[order.answer,])
      answer1[1,1]
    } else {
      stop("invalid measure")
    }
  } else {
    stop("invalid state")
  }
  ##
}
##
> lowestV2("NY","MSAT")
[1] "Oswego"
```

Unless you are doing error catching for some type of complex situation / condition, you might as well just include the handling directly in the main function rather than make calls to external error handling functions for each condition.

Answer (score 1):

Argument checking can be done with the `checkmate` package (from [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/checkmate/index.html)).

Load the data:

```
school <- c("NYU", "BYU", "USC", "FIT", "Oswego","UCLA","USF","Columbia")
stateList <- c("NY","UT","CA","NY","NY","CA", "CA","NY")
measureList <- c("MSAT","MSAT","GPA","MSAT","MSAT","GPA","GPA","GPA")
score <- c(590, 490, 2.9, 759, 550, 1.2, 3.1, 3.2)
data <- data.frame(school, stateList, measureList, score)
```

Load the package, and add tests to function:

```
library(checkmate)

lowest <- function (State, Measure) {
  expect_subset(State, stateList, empty.ok=FALSE, info="invalid state")
  expect_subset(Measure, measureList, empty.ok=FALSE, info="invalid measure")

  # if you also want to restrict to single states and measures
  assert_atomic(State, len=1)
  assert_atomic(Measure, len=1)

  answer<-subset(data,subset=(stateList==State & measureList==Measure))
  order.answer<-order(answer$score,answer$school)
  answer1<-as.matrix(answer[order.answer,])
  answer1[1,1]
}
```

Test our new function:

```
lowest("NY","MSAT")
# [1] "Oswego"
lowest("NJ","MSAT")
# Error with message 'invalid state'
lowest("NY","blah")
# Error with message 'invalid measure'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this function accomplishes what you want:

```
school<-c("NYU", "BYU", "USC", "FIT", "Oswego","UCLA","USF","Columbia")
state<-c("NY","UT","CA","NY","NY","CA", "CA","NY")
measure<-c("MSAT","MSAT","GPA","MSAT","MSAT","GPA","GPA","GPA")
score<-c(590, 490, 2.9, 759, 550, 1.2, 3.1, 3.2)
data<-data.frame(school,state, measure,score)

lowest <- function(State, Measure,Statelist,Measurelist,Data){
  if (!State%in%Statelist){
    stop("invalid state")
  }
  if (! Measure%in%Measurelist){
    stop("invalid measure")
  }
  else{
    answer<-subset(data,subset=(state==State & measure==Measure))
    order.answer<-order(answer$score,answer$school)
    answer1<-as.matrix(answer[order.answer,])
    print(answer1[1,1])
  }
}

lowest("NY","MSAT",state,measure,data)
```

It also enables you to give the function different lists of states, measures and datasets without altering the function itself.